# Android GridView - one item with full width

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout

Trying to allow 1 item in my GridView (2 columns) to have the full width of 2 items.

Is this possible without using another layout?
Only found solutions involving setting up another layout outside the gridview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you that you should be using the recyclerview instead of Gridview. And the thing you want from gridView can easily done by following bellow link.

[Link is here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html)

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() 
    {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) 
        {
            return position == 0 ? 2 : 1;
        }
    });
```